Neovim: module 'lazy' still not found
I'm on Ubuntu via WSL. I've 'installed' neovim by copying the AppImage (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/latest/download/nvim.appimage) into ~/.local/bin/, making it executable with chmod, and adding the path to PATH. The program is found and launches; the version is
>> nvim -v
NVIM v0.10.2
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1713484068
Run "nvim -V1 -v" for more info

However, upon launch I get the following error message:
Error detected while processing /root/.dotfiles/neovim/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /root/.config/nvim/lua/lazy-plugins.lua:12: module 'lazy' not found:
        no field package.preload['lazy']
        no file './lazy.lua'
        no file '/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/share/luajit-2.1/lazy.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lazy.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lazy/init.lua'
        no file '/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/share/lua/5.1/lazy.lua'
        no file '/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/share/lua/5.1/lazy/init.lua'
        no file './lazy.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lazy.so'
        no file '/home/runner/work/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/lib/lua/5.1/lazy.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /root/.config/nvim/lua/lazy-plugins.lua:12: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /root/.dotfiles/neovim/nvim/init.lua:24: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue

I've read this question but the listed answers are not working for me.
/.local/share/nvim/lazy/ is created when the program launches, but it's empty. Deleting the folder does not make a difference.
Any ideas as to what else I could try?
